# Does the union of the spans of two subspaces span their sum?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm not sure if it's is a duplicate question, but  sure that I didn't find my answer in similar questions.

I found that $F+G= \operatorname{span}(F\cup G)$.
However, while solving a question, my prof. used another equality which is,
 $F+G= \operatorname{span}(\operatorname{span}(F)\cup \operatorname{span}(G))$. Are the two same? If not, which is the right one? I'm really confused about this. Can anyone help me?

Comment: If $F$ and $G$ are two subspaces, then $F=$span($F$) and $G=$span($G$).

Answer (score 1):

$F\subseteq \text{span}(F)$ and similarly for $G$. So, if $F+G = \text{span}(F\cup G)$, then the second equality is also true. Proving the reverse equality is fairly simple. Take any element of $\text{span}(\text{span}(F)\cup \text{span}(G))$ and show that it can be written as a linear combination only of elements in $F$ and/or $G$.